# How to normalize a histogram of an exponential distributionin scipy?

Tags: python, numpy, distribution

I'm trying to fit an exponential distribution to a dataset I have. Strangely, no matter what I do I can't seem to scale the histogram so it fits the fitted exponential distribution.

```
param=expon.fit(data)
pdf_fitted=norm.pdf(x,loc=param[0],scale=param[1])
plot(x,pdf_fitted,'r-')
hist(constraint1N55, normed=1,alpha=.3,histtype='stepfilled')
```

[image: Probability distribution. Note how the histogram has much more area than the exponential fit.]

For some reason, the histogram takes up much more space than the probability distribution, even though I have normed=1. Is there something I can do to make things fit more appropriately?

Comment: I am not sure what are you asking about... What do you want? Did you check the fit values? The fitting looks pretty mediocre for me, what is it the MSE of it? You got a fit and you plotted the model for the fit values, not sure what you expect. If it looks bad, either the fit does not work properly or the model is bad. Maybe your data does not follow the normal distribution. It actually looks like hyperbolic would be better.

Comment: My problem is just with the normalization of either the histogram or the probability distribution. The area under the curves should the same, no? Also: what's a hyperbolic distribution and is it implemented in scipy?

Comment: I assumed the y-scale is the same for both, since there is only one y-axis. Isn't it? For now certainly the areas do not match. But when you have a bad fit, they won't. Can't you sum areas and integrate the fit to check which one is not normalized ?

Comment: Could you work a little bit more on your code? I want to do the same thing but I don't know what is `x` or `data`, is it the result from the `plt.hist` thing or the raw data???

Answer (score 5):

You made an error. You fitted to an exponential, but plotted a normal distribution:

```
pdf_fitted=expon.pdf(x,loc=param[0],scale=param[1])
```

The data looks good when plotted properly:

[image]